# GKSession: Sending an Array of Strings

Tags: ios, nsstring, bluetooth, nsdata, gksession

I'd like one peer in a session to send an array of strings to another, connected peer. Is there a way to convert such an array into NSData or do I need to send the strings one after another? 
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `NSArray` of `NSString` objects is a property list.  You can convert it to an `NSData` like this:

```
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:myArray
    format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0
    options:0
    error:&error];
```

You can convert the data back to a property list like this:

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *myArray = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data
    options:NSPropertyListImmutable
    format:NULL
    error:&error];
```